# Enforcing initial containment of a JQuery draggable

Tags: jquery, xhtml, jquery-ui-draggable, containment

For a photography webpage I am implementing an image viewer that allows for selecting an area of interest in a scaled-down reference image by dragging a semi-transparent rectangle over the reference image. The selected area is continuously "mirrored" to a second image viewer, which shows the area with at 100% magnification ratio.

My solution uses XHTML/CSS and jQuery and I have a basic version that is working already – but suffers from a problem at initialization, which I cannot solve. I have set up the area of interest as a `div` that is made draggable using jQuery UI draggable. To constrain the area of interest to the image, I have used the `containment` property.

Initially the div is however shown outside of the image. As soon as I start dragging the area of interest `div`, the `div` snaps to the interior of the image and containment is properly enforced henceforth. All sample code I found, demonstrates containment with nested `div`s, which does not apply to my case since to my knowledge an image (XHML `img`) cannot contain other elements.

Is there a way how I can enforce that the draggable area of interest `div` is already contained when the webpage is initially rendered?

I have extracted to minimal code to illustrate the problem from my code, see below.

I will be glad for any hint.

Cheers,
 Christian

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#zoom_area").draggable( {
            containment: '#the_image'
        });
    });

    </script>

<style type="text/css">

#the_image {
    width: 640px;
    height: 427px;
}

#zoom_area {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="image_viewer">
    <img id="the_image" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="reference image" />
</div>

<div id="zoom_area">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. First, you can try doing it without an image tag. Try placing #zoom_area inside #image_viewer, and using a CSS background image to include the image rather than an image tage.

HTML:

```
<div id="the_image">    
    <div id="zoom_area"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#the_image {
    width: 640px;
    height: 427px;
    background-image:url('img/img1.jpg');
}

#zoom_area {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

See this first example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/qUtEW/

If you need to use an image tag, then you can use the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="image_viewer"> 
        <img id="the_image" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="reference image" /> 
        <div id="zoom_area"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#the_image {
    width: 640px;
    height: 427px;
}

#zoom_area {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top:10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

The trick here is to set position absolute and z-index 10.

See this second example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/pBRgb/

Comment: Thanks @Adam I used your second solution and it works flawlessly. I did not fully understand what you meant by your remark "if you need an IMG". Is there a specific situation in which you would prefer one solution over the other? Also, your second solution uses the same id for the `div` and the `img`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @SwedishChef - I don't know how the rest of your code works. I imagine there might be a situation where your application requires an image tag to exist on the page. That's what I mean by "if you need an IMG". The id was a typo - the div should have the id #image_viewer. I edited the answer to reflect that. Good luck.